# WordPress: Own content after every more-tag

Tags: php, wordpress, wysiwyg

I want to display content everytime I'm using a more-tag in the editor.
I found a solution to do this for the first more-tag with this code:

```
<?php if ($pos=strpos($post->post_content, '<!--more-->')): ?>
<?php $more = 0; the_content(''); ?>
<div>CONTENT HERE</div>
<?php $more = 1; the_content('', true); ?>
<?php else : the_content(); endif; ?>
```

Is there any way to do this for every more-tag in the content?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you think about this?

```
<?php 
$contenido="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, his id porro lucilius theophrastus. -mas- Eum labitur voluptaria te, magna veniam civibus -mas- ad mei. An per ornatus officiis quaerendum, sonet timeam ad eam, nec an vidisse discere intellegam. Iusto habemus reprimique an nec.";

$contenidoExploded=explode('-mas-',$contenido);

if(count($contenidoExploded)>1){
    foreach($contenidoExploded as $p){
        echo $p.'</p>';   
    }
}else{
    echo $contenido;
}
```

It works for you?